# Getting android displaymetrics for mobile site?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

Is there any way to get android displaymetrics for mobile site built in angularjs ? i have to fetch images based on the android displaymetrics (screen resolution of mobile device)
like :

```
DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
              width = 298;
              height = 163;
DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
              width = 397;
              height = 250;
```

Answer (score 0):

use screen object

```
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;
```